# SQL Server 2005 Database Backup

Tags: sql-server-2005

> i m created a Database Backup job in SQL server 2005 under maintainace Plan,
>   but when  i run below query SQL sever return 0 Rows

Why?

select * from   sysdbmaintplan_databases

> I want to retrive Using SQL Query Created Job for Database Backup  with Database name & Path.

Answer (score 0):

This table is for backwards compatibility. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190308.aspx).

Comment: Does this help? http://solihinho.wordpress.com/2009/01/01/query-for-listing-sql-server-job-schedule/

Edit: this comment in reply to a now-deleted comment.

Comment: thanx for your help ..but it doesnot return Database Name & Path